# In what book did Harry Potter start showing affection towards Ginny Weasley?

Tags: harry-potter, love

Does anyone know at what point in the Harry Potter books Harry started showing affection towards Ginny Weasley?

Answer (score 12):

*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* is where their relationship goes into full swing. Harry sees Ginny kissing Dean and realises that he's jealous.

> Harry hardly noticed the sound of shattering glass; he felt
> disorientated, dizzy; being struck by a lightning bolt must be
> something like this. It’s just because she’s Ron’s sister, he told
> himself. You just didn’t like seeing her kissing Dean because she’s
> Ron’s sister …
>
> But unbidden into his mind came an image of that same deserted
> corridor with himself kissing Ginny instead … the monster in his chest
> purred … but then he saw Ron ripping open the tapestry curtain and
> drawing his wand on Harry, shouting things like ‘betrayal of trust’ …
> ‘supposed to be my friend’ …
>
> <sub><sup>*Chapter 14: Felix Felicis*</sup></sub>

A few chapters later Harry contemplates asking Ginny out after she breaks up with Dean...

> The battle still raged inside his head: Ginny or Ron? Sometimes he
> thought that the post-Lavender Ron might not mind too much if he asked
> Ginny out, but then he remembered Ron’s expression when he had seen
> her kissing Dean, and was sure that Ron would consider it base
> treachery if Harry so much as held her hand …
>
> <sub><sup>*Chapter 24 - Sectumsempra*</sup></sub>

...and shortly afterwards kisses her in front of everyone, after her triumphant Quidditch match.

> Harry looked around; there was Ginny running towards him; she had a
> hard, blazing look in her face as she threw her arms around him. And
> without thinking, without planning it, without worrying about the fact
> that fifty people were watching, Harry kissed her.
>
> After several long moments – or it might have been half an hour – or
> possibly several sunlit days – they broke apart. The room had gone
> very quiet. Then several people wolf-whistled and there was an
> outbreak of nervous giggling. Harry looked over the top of Ginny’s
> head to see Dean Thomas holding a shattered glass in his hand and
> Romilda Vane looking as though she might throw something. Hermione was
> beaming, but Harry’s eyes sought Ron. At last he found him, still
> clutching the Cup and wearing an expression appropriate to having been
> clubbed over the head. For a fraction of a second they looked at each
> other, then Ron gave a tiny jerk of the head that Harry understood to
> mean, ‘Well – if you must.’

---

In the film series the order of events is slightly different. Ginny and Harry's first kiss is secret and happens when they're hiding the potions textbook.

> **GINNY:** *All right. Close your eyes. That way you can’t be tempted.*
>
> Ginny slips the book from his fingers and starts to back away. She mouths: Close... your... eyes. As she leaves
> FRAME, CAMERA PUSHES EVER-SO-SLOWLY IN ON Harry. Still.
> Waiting. For a long moment, there is only silence. Then a shadow gently eclipses Harry’s face.
>
> **GINNY:** *There’s something else. Another secret of sorts. One of mine...*
>
> Ginny leans in then and places her mouth on Harry’s.
>
> **GINNY:** *That can stay hidden up here too, if you like.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Screenplay](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/potter6.pdf)</sup></sub>

Comment: Awesome! I vividly remember the "roaring monster in Harry's chest" from the book, but I didn't remember that scene from the movie. Now I want to watch it again.

Comment: Is that the first time though?